# Update Django via settings to new domain

Tags: django, nginx

I'm new to Django and nginx.

I have built a default Django app and my setup uses a nginx server as a reverse proxy. My application was previously reached via https://myapplication.intranet and every internal link referred to this link (e.g. href "/" points to "https://myapplication.intranet/" and href points to "/test" "https://myapplication.intranet/test") - so everything worked.

Now nginx changed the domain link to "https://myapplication.intranet/new/", and everything broke:

- redirect (e.g. in view.py)
- href (in html templates. For example href "/test" incorrectly points to "https://myapplication.intranet/test" instead of "https://myapplication.intranet/new/test")
- css sheets not found

My question is the following: What adjustments have to be made (for Django) in order to make the application work again? Is there an easier (and more general) way than rewriting all links in all files to make the urls specific?

Thank you very much.